# How to use schemaAttribute as a string for Array in normalizr

Tags: normalizr

I was looking into the [docs](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr/blob/master/docs/api.md#arraydefinition-schemaattribute) about array schema and under the **schemaAttribute** option it says that we can pass a string and it is optional for one schema.

I've tried lots of combinations but I can't get it done, I get errors or my data is not normalized correctly.

For example:

```
const adminSchema = new schema.Entity('admins');

const myArray = new schema.Array({
  new: adminSchema
}, 'new');
```

or

```
const myArray = new schema.Array(adminSchema, 'new');
```

How can I achieve this?

Beside that, what would be the reason of it?

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the source code I realised how I can use it

```
const data = [ { id: 1, type: 'admins' }, { the_ID: 2, type: 'users' } ];

const userSchema = new schema.Entity('users', {}, {
  idAttribute: 'the_ID'
});

const adminSchema = new schema.Entity('admins');

const myArray = new schema.Array({
  admins: adminSchema, users: userSchema 
}, 'type');
```